# Exposing protected API without hardcoding credentials in the Client (JS)

Tags: authentication, web-application, appsec, rest

Try to expose protected REST API without exposing credentials in the Client (JS Code).

All solutions that come to my mind, can be reversed and the Attacker can 
reconstruct them.

Are there any proven solutions? Best practices?

Ideas, I came up for example:

1. Obfuscating credentials
2. Hashing client side set of elements and comparing server side to
   make sure the Client is untouched (not used by the Attacker)

can be reversed.

Unfortunately, HTTPS authentication does not come into play, since the website accessing the REST API (Client, JS Code) should be open to the public. I cannot request each Client (Website visitor) to request a PKC (Public Key Certificate)

```
HTTPS Client Authentication

HTTPS Client Authentication requires the client to possess a Public Key 
Certificate (PKC). 
If you specify client authentication, the web server will authenticate the 
client using the client’s public key certificate.
HTTPS Client Authentication is a more secure method of authentication than 
either basic or form-based authentication. It uses HTTP over SSL (HTTPS), 
in which the server authenticates the client using the client’s Public Key 
Certificate (PKC). Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) technology provides data encryption,
server authentication, message integrity, and optional client authentication for a 
TCP/IP connection. You can think of a public key certificate as the digital 
equivalent of a passport. It is issued by a trusted organization, which 
is called a certificate authority (CA), and provides identification for 
the bearer.
```

I want to prevent that people will obtain credentials and scrape/perform many request to REST API.

I guess, our only solution is than IP based throttling? To punish bad Clients.

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1:**

After Discussions with @ThoriumBR, came up with this solution. Not optimal but should be better than nothing.

**Design:**

Client Website <-> New API (Proxy) <-> Old API

**Flow:**

Wrap old API (private) against new API (public, in diagram above Proxy)

1) Client Website makes Request to Proxy

2) Proxy Sends CAPCHA back

3) Client Website complete CAPCHA

4) Proxy creates JWT (assign capcha intrval in JWT for example as 10 (capcha_int:10), assign deviceid: fingerprint (to know the users from the same IP)) sends it back to Client Website. Proxy checks also for abuse, if deviceid is misbehaving, it will be blocked.

5) Website Send request to Proxy with JWT

6) Proxy check JWT, if capcha interval (capcha_int) is equal 10 send CAPCHA, resets it, if it misbehaves, if not, sends request to old API

7) old Api sends reponse via Proxy to Client Website

IPs will be IP based Throttled for abuse. (second layer to prevent abuse)

Comment: How about using a proxy on the server, and JWT to authenticate the clients?

Comment: But don't the client would need to somehow authenticate to JWT ... so I have to expose JWT auth, which the Attacker/Malicious user can redo. So I get to the same scenario .... No?

Comment: No, it will not expose the JWT (and the token expiration is short anyway). Client authenticates on the endpoint, receives the token, uses token until it expires in minutes. Expired? Authenticate again. Abused? Ban the user.

Comment: Thanks. The Client (Website with JS Code) will be publicly open. No need to authenticate for the visitor. Each visitor will be seen as the same. In your scenario I would have to `authenticate on the endpoint`, which means some credentials would need to be passed (user has to know them or they will have to be hardcoded in the Client). I hope you understand my point or maybe I am missing something obvious about JWT.

Comment: `To punish bad clients` and `Each visitor will be seen as the same` cannot work together. Or you have a way do tell a client from the other, or you cannot punish bad clients. If you don't have any kind of login, there's no way to punish anyone. Client JS can be public, but you will need a login.

Comment: Or you mean to give JWT token to every visitor ... if somebody with a certain token abuses the API, block that token ... yea, but he can than just get a new JWT... so again we are at the beginning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81945/discussion-between-thoriumbr-and-android-dev).

Comment: `Each visitor will be seen as the same` on application logic level. Will be different on IP level. I guess the ONLY solution is to do the IP based throttling in that case than ....

Comment: @android_dev To remove doubt: are you saying you have a publicly-accessible website, that uses JS to talk to a REST API and you want to ensure that only your JS code can make calls to the API? You want to stop someone "lifting" the API-calling code and either making their own website, or perform command-line scraping of the API?

Comment: @TripeHound Yes

Comment: you have to put the API behind your site, typically with a php relay script, otherwise you'd have to share your credentials with every visitor.

Comment: @android_dev Then I _suspect_ you're out of luck, without having some kind of login/authentication for you normal visitors. Essentially (as I think I understand it), anything you do in the browser to "prove" it's your JS making the API calls can be duplicated by an attacker (including returning hashes of client-side elements etc.).